# Convert binary string to binary literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.2.2.

I'm looking for a function that converts a binary string, e.g. '0b1010' or '1010', into a binary literal, e.g. 0b1010 (not a string or a decimal integer literal).

It's an easy matter to roll-my-own, but I prefer to use either a standard function or one that is well-established: I don't want to 're-invent the wheel.'

Regardless, I'm happy look at any efficient algorithms y'all might have.

Answer (score 23):

The string **is** a literal.

```
3>> bin(int('0b1010', 2))
'0b1010'
3>> bin(int('1010', 2))
'0b1010'
3>> 0b1010
10
3>> int('0b1010', 2)
10
```

Comment: Thanks. The output from those operations are strings and decimal integers. I want a binary literal sent to stdout. Thanks, again.

Comment: Did you try `print('0b1010')`?

Comment: That works, but it is still a string. I shouldn't have mentioned stdout: I need a function that returns true binary int. I realize that returning a decimal int would most often be as effective, but I want a bin int. Thx, Ignacio.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "binary integer". Integers are integers, and are radix-independent. Only literals (input) and representations (output) are radix-dependent.

Comment: actually, to be more precise, in python there is no such thing as decimal integer, all integers are binary in memory.

Comment: Only because memory uses binary for storage. It could just as easily store the same integer in trinary, octal, or biquinary (assuming sufficient radix places).

Comment: Forget the semantics: I understand. Need function that returns repr(0b11)=0b11, not = 3 or ='0b11'.

Comment: Then you'll never be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
#!python3

def fn(s, base=10):
    prefix = s[0:2]
    if prefix == '0x':
        base = 16
    elif prefix == '0b':
        base = 2
    return bin(int(s, base))


print(fn('15'))
print(fn('0xF'))
print(fn('0b1111'))
```

If you are sure you have `s = "'0b010111'"` and you only want to get `010111`, then you can just slice the middle like:

```
s = s[2:-1]
```

i.e. from index 2 to the one before the last.

But as Ignacio and Antti wrote, numbers are abstract. The `0b11` is one of the string representations of the number 3 the same ways as `3` is another string representation of the number 3.

The `repr()` always returns *a string*. The only thing that can be done with the `repr` result is to strip the apostrophes -- because the `repr` adds the apostrophes to the string representation to emphasize it is the string representation. If you want a binary representation of a number (as a string without apostrophes) then `bin()` is the ultimate answer.

Comment: What if you want to use the number in a calculation?  We can for instance use `0b1 ^ 0b10` but not `'0b1' ^ '0b10'`, and using `bin` doesn't change this.

Comment: @dsaxton: The `bin()` returns a string representation as a binary number. When doing the exclusive or operation, you want to keep it as an abstract number. For that case, you simply remove the bin wrapper at the return line (but this was not the question). Or you can write a function that implements the xor operation on string representation of bits.